# Displaying contents of a Text file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am brand new to using ajax, and I am really lost. I am trying to have it where I have four countries (usa, Canada, mexico, and Russia) and when the user chooses a country with  radio button, it will grab one of 4 text files, then display what cities are in the country. (those cities are within the text file) Can anybody help? Apperently the text files are located on another site.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <!-- This is assign09.html -->
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title> Ajax </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadXMLDoc() {
            req=new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (req.readyState==4 && req.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML=req.responseText;
                }
            } // end of onreadstatechange function
            req.open("GET","usa.txt",true);
            req.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Countries</h1>
    <form name="submission" action="">
        <input type="radio" name="countries" id="usa" value="1">USA</br>
        <input type="radio" name="countries" id="canada" value="2">Canada</br>
        <input type="radio" name="countries" id="mexico" value="3">Mexico</br>
        <input type="radio" name="countries" id="russia" value="4">Russia</br>

        <button class="buttonS" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: On my teacher's site. But I want to have it so that when they choose a certain country, it will pull up a different text file (i.e. mexico.txt, etc). The files are on "http://157.201.194.254/~ercanbracks"

Comment: If possible, you should use jQuery and it's get function.

Comment: We haven't done jQuery yet. It's only supposed to be done in ajax

Comment: How would I use jQuery?

Comment: If you're using ajax, you probably don't want your button to actually do a form submit. You want to add an event listener and call your loadXMLDoc function from there.

Comment: Ok that sounds good. Would I just add a few IF statements within the loadXMLDoc function to determine which text file I want to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery would be the best possible way to perform an AJAX request. Since different browsers handle AJAX requests a little differently, the jQuery team has taken care of this so that you can write universal AJAX functions.